# Missing permissions when attempting to create dataproc cluster using java libraries

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-iam

I'm attempting to create a dataproc cluster using the https://github.com/googleapis/java-dataproc library, following the example here: https://github.com/googleapis/java-dataproc/blob/main/samples/snippets/src/main/java/CreateCluster.java

My (translated to scala) code:

```
import com.google.cloud.dataproc.v1._

object CreateCluster extends App {

  val projectId = "my-project-id"
  val region = "europe-west1"
  val clusterName = "test-cluster"

  val regionEndpoint = s"$region-dataproc.googleapis.com:443"
  
  val clusterControllerSettings = ClusterControllerSettings.newBuilder()
    .setEndpoint(regionEndpoint)
    .build()

  val clusterControllerClient = ClusterControllerClient.create(clusterControllerSettings)

  val masterConfig = InstanceGroupConfig.newBuilder.setMachineTypeUri("n1-standard-2").setNumInstances(1).build
  val workerConfig = InstanceGroupConfig.newBuilder.setMachineTypeUri("n1-standard-2").setNumInstances(2).build
  val clusterConfig = ClusterConfig.newBuilder.setMasterConfig(masterConfig).setWorkerConfig(workerConfig).build

  val cluster = Cluster.newBuilder().setClusterName(clusterName).setConfig(clusterConfig).build()

  val createClusterAsyncRequest = clusterControllerClient.createClusterAsync(projectId, region, cluster)

  val createResponse: Cluster = createClusterAsyncRequest.get()

  println(s"Created cluster: ${createResponse.getClusterName}")

  clusterControllerClient.close()

}
```

I'm getting `io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Required 'compute.regions.get' permission for 'projects/my-project/regions/europe-west1'`.

I'm unclear as to exactly what is meant here: https://github.com/googleapis/java-dataproc#authorization. I'm trying to get this to work from my desktop so what I've done is run `gcloud auth application-default login --scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute.readonly`.

I'm certain my 'normal' user has the necessary permissions as I've executed a 'regions.get' for my project/region from this page: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/regions/get, and can create dataproc clusters not using the java library without issue.

I'm clearly missing something, probably something obvious, but am stuck so any help will be greatly appreciated!

---

### Edit 1:

`gcloud auth application-default login` without specifying --scopes results in the same permission error

---

### Edit 2:

I'm still none the wiser as to why I'm getting the `compute.regions.get` permission missing error.

I've written some more code which appears to show I do have the necessary permission when using `getApplicationDefault`:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory
import com.google.api.services.compute.Compute
import com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault

object GetRegions extends App {

  val project = "my-project-id"
  val region = "europe-west1"

  val httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport
  val jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance
  val httpCredentials = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(getApplicationDefault)

  val computeService =  new Compute.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, httpCredentials).build

  val request = computeService.regions.get(project, region)
  val response = request.execute

  System.out.println(response) // This successfully prints out details

}
```

Comment: You do not need to specify scopes for the command **gcloud auth application-default login** except for special cases. Try the command again with no scopes. Note: the scope **cloud-platform** includes the other scopes so those are redundant.

Comment: Ah should have mentioned I’d initially tried without specifying the scopes, same issue…

Comment: That means the user you logged in with does not have permission. Double check with this command `gcloud projects get-iam-policy <YOUR GCP PROJECT> 
--flatten="bindings[].members" 
--format="table(bindings.role)" 
--filter="bindings.members:<THE USER OR SERVICE ACCOUNT>"`

Comment: I don't have permission to run that query, which isn't super surprising given I'm in a corporate environment.

I have verified (a different way to in my original post) that I do have the 'compute.regions.get' permission. I went to here: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/testIamPermissions, added in 'my-project' as the resource and 'compute.regions.get' into the body, and observed that 'compute.regions.get' is returned. For additional sanity check, I can prove using this method that I don't have the "resourcemanager.projects.getIamPolicy" permission.

Comment: This code does work in a sandpit environment where I'm owner, so you're right...it's definitely permission issues. Really surprised I don't appear to have the necessary permissions, since I can start clusters just fine from the cli/web interface, but I must be missing something daft.

Comment: @JohnHanley  Whilst I try and get someone with the correct privileges to run your query, can you think of any reason why the 'GetRegions' code I've just added to the question would work but the dataproc code fails? As I understand it, the 'GetRegions' code is using the permission the dataproc error claims I don't have?

Comment: Edit your question and include the output from the **get-iam-policy** command above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out it was the permissions of the dataproc service agent that were missing this permission, not my user (these had been modified from default permissions).

See https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/iam/dataproc-principals#service_agent_control_plane_identity.

Not explicitly setting the zone when creating a cluster seems to mean that this service account requires the `compute.regions.get` permission. Explicitly setting a zone meant it didn't.